# TimeZone Abbreviation issue with new version of moment-timezone js package

Tags: timezone, momentjs

After updating (to 0.5.x) moment-timezone facing issue with abbreviation which used to work fine earlier (0.3.x)

Following is the code to test:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var momentTz = require('moment-timezone');
var now = 
moment.tz(new Date('Thu Sep 14 2017 07:32:17 GMT+0000 (UTC)'),'Asia/Dubai');
console.log("now.zoneAbbr()");
console.log(now.zoneAbbr());
console.log("now.zoneName()");
console.log(now.zoneName());
console.log("format");
console.log(now.format('ha z'));
console.log(now)
```

Moment-TimeZone Version "0.3.1":
Output:

> now.zoneAbbr() 
>   GST 
>   now.zoneName() 
>   GST 
>   format 
>   11am GST 
>   moment.parseZone("2017-09-14T11:32:17.000+04:00")

Moment-TimeZone Version "0.5.x":
Output:

> now.zoneAbbr()
>   +04
>   now.zoneName()
>   +04
>   format
>   11am +04
>   moment.parseZone("2017-09-14T11:32:17.000+04:00")

I believe something is wrong in my understanding if this is a betterment of moment-timezone or I think the problem is in this change `/moment-timezone/data/packed/latest.json` 
e.g. version 0.5.x (Line No.188)

```
"Asia/Dubai|LMT +04|-3F.c -40|01|-21JfF.c|39e5"
```

e.g. version 0.3.x (Line No.188)

```
"Asia/Dubai|LMT GST|-3F.c -40|01|-21JfF.c"
```

Could anyone put some more light on this issue?

Comment: https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/525

Comment: See my answer in the dup link.  Also in another context [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42303406/634824).  And addressed in your github issue as well.