# Getting the timezone name by giving a time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, momentjs

I'm trying to get the timezone name by giving the time with javascript
, for example

This given date

```
(GMT-12:00) International Date Line West
```

Would give me this timezone name.

```
Dateline Standard Time
```

Here is a list of timezone names time that i need to convert into.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/973627/microsoft-time-zone-index-values

I've checked Moment.js but I couldn't find any.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46214439/4131048) and have a look at the linked answers, I fear that it is not possible to achieve it.